# Opening and closing time to store app

Tags: ios

I am working on a objective C store app. I do not want people buying things in different times each day of the week. I need some thing that would be like,"Mon- Thu: 11:00 am - 11:00 pm
Fri - Sat: 11:00 am - 12:00 am
Sun: 11:00 am - 10:00 pm".

When you push a UIbutton It would not let the buys go past and it would say a message like "We are closed" or "Come back later".

If any one could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current time by creating a new `NSDate` object with the `[NSDate date]` method. If you want to know some particular information about that date, I would recommend using `NSCalendar`'s `components:fromDate:` method to get some information about the time. You can also perform comparison using the `NSDateComponent`s you get from that method. More information [here on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsdatecomponents/)

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func displayStoreClosedMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    if isStoreOpenNow() {
        //Show a message saying the store is OPEN
    } else {
        //Show a message saying the store is CLOSED
    }
}

func isStoreOpenNow() -> Bool {
    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Weekday, NSCalendarUnit.Hour], fromDate: NSDate())
    switch components.day {

    case 1: //Sun
        switch components.hour {
        case 11..<22: //11am - 10pm
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    case 2...5: //Mon to Thurs
        switch components.hour {
        case 11..<23: //11am - 11pm
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    case 6...7: //Sat
        switch components.hour {
        case 11...23: //11am - 12am
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    default: //Just because we have to
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! it helped a lot! but it says "Unexpected "@" in program"?